# Background color when text-align is right

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div>
    <p class="highlight-date">2009-4-5</p>
</dvi>
```

and here is the css:

```
div{
    width: 200px;
}

div p{
    text-align: right;
}

.highlight-date{
    background-color: yellow;
}​
```

I'd like to have the background color to be just under the text, but now it would extend from the left of the div. How could I fix this? thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6exa/

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can fix it:  http://jsfiddle.net/f6exa/1/

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
}

.highlight-date{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Changes:

1. Move the `text-align: right` from the content (p) to the container (div).
2. Make the content (p) `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Much better than my solution. CSS wizard.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
    <span class="highlight-date">2009-4-5</span>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    div
    {
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .highlight-date
    {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    ​</style>
```

Comment: Changes:
 

1.Remove <p> tag - without this, we can acheive the requirement inside the <div> with text align right.
 
2.Keep all content inside the <span> tag with class "highlight-date"

Comment: You cud have edited this answer instead of posting a new one!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span class="highlight-date">2009-4-5</span></p>
</dvi>
```